# Oracle SQL: Why is my function outputting null?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status_by_member_id
(p_member_id NUMBER) 
RETURN CHAR
AS
  v_status CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  select status
  into v_status
  from members
  where member_id = p_member_id;
  if v_status is null then
    return v_status || 'N';
  else
     return v_status;
  end if;
END get_status_by_member_id;
```

Comment: FWIW - It's helpful if you give some context and your intuitions on the problem.

Comment: What is the type of member_id?  Could there be duplicates in the table?  In other words, perhaps the query is returning an error, so you are getting NULL because of a premature return and an undetected error.

Comment: can you update the question with `desc members` and a small snippet of output from `select status,member_id from members;`?

Comment: @Bianca, you said `even if I do return 'N', it outputs null.` it looks like your display code maybe the suspect.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is caused by a, sometimes, annoying quirk of Oracle. Namely that if a PL/SQL function is called in SQL and errors then `null` is returned, rather than anything else.

If I create a very simple table...

```
create table a ( b number, c varchar2(1) );
insert into a values (1,'Y');
```

... and two functions. One with *no* exception handling

```
create or replace function tmp_ben_fn (PId number) return char is
   l_status varchar2(1);   
begin  

   select c
     into l_status
     from a
    where b = PId;

   return coalesce(l_status, 'N');

end;
/
```

and one with exception handling.

```
create or replace function tmp_ben_fn2 (PId number) return char is
   l_status varchar2(1);   
begin  

   select c
     into l_status
     from a
    where b = PId;

   return coalesce(l_status, 'N');

   exception when no_data_found then
      return 'A';

end;
/
```

Then, we use these two functions to select the data. Remember we only have one row, so we're expecting only `Y` or `N` to be returned:

```
SQL> -- Expected output Y
SQL> select tmp_ben_fn(1) from dual;

TMP_BEN_FN2(1)
-------------------------------------------------

Y

SQL> -- Expected output, Error no_data_found
SQL> -- as row 2 does not exist.
SQL> select tmp_ben_fn(2) from dual;

TMP_BEN_FN(2)
-------------------------------------------------



SQL> -- Expected output, the same as tmp_ben_fn
SQL> select tmp_ben_fn2(2) from dual;

TMP_BEN_FN2(2)
-------------------------------------------------

A

SQL>
```

As you can see in the function with no error handling, when a `no_data_found` exception occurs a `null` is returned. When we capture the exception, we get the expected `A` instead.

I suspect that the `member_id` you're trying to select does not exist.

As a general rule: Always be aware when an exception might occur, `select into...` being a particularly worrisome example with the opportunity to select both too many and no rows. If your table is unique on `member_id` then you should change your function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status_by_member_id (p_member_id NUMBER) 
RETURN CHAR IS
  v_status CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  select status
  into v_status
  from members
  where member_id = p_member_id;

  return v_status;

-- If the member_id does not exist
-- return N
exception when no_data_found then
   return 'N';
END get_status_by_member_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an exception handler to your code, as in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status_by_member_id 
  (p_member_id NUMBER) RETURN CHAR 
as 
  v_status CHAR(1); 
begin 
  BEGIN
    select status 
      into v_status 
      from members 
      where member_id = p_member_id;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      v_status := NULL;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      v_status := NULL;
  END;

  if v_status is null then 
    return 'N'; 
  else 
    return v_status; 
  end if; 
end get_status_by_member_id;
```

This will handle the cases where there's no data which matches p_member_id, or where there are multiple rows which match p_member_id.  This may or may not correct the issues you're seeing.  It would be helpful if you would edit your post and add in the code you're using which calls `get_status_by_member_id`.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: In case there were `NO DATA FOUND` error in the `SELECT` the function call would have aborted and failed while performing the `SELECT INTO`. But in OPs case, it executes successfully but returns `NULL`. I agree with the exception handling part, but I also think that's not causing the issue here.

Comment: @Annjawn: my thinking is that if the function were called from a client program and return codes were not checked, etc, it's entirely possible that it could appear that the function executed correctly and returned NULL.  That's about the only scenario I can picture where this function could 'return' NULL, and is why I tried wrapping an exception handler around the SQL.